# Recorrer collection en laravel y obtener datos específicos de la collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

estoy tratando de recorrer una collection y necesito obtener un listado de productos de acuerdo a ciertas claves. pero me sale el sgte error cuando imprimo el listado con dd:

> `"array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer"`

Esta es la colleccion de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Función principal donde obtengo la collection:

```
public function storeTranspor($request){

  DB::table('transpor')->truncate();
  $var = DB::select("select flu.zona, flu.destino, flu.producto, pro.especie, sup.codigo, dtr.cod_fundo, sup.sup_ha, dtr.dist_pavimento, dtr.dist_no_pavimento, dtr.peaje 
  from flujos flu 
  left join super sup on (sup.zona = flu.zona) 
  left join d_transporte dtr on (dtr.cod_fundo = (sup.codigo / 1000000) and dtr.destino = flu.destino) 
  left join productos pro on (pro.producto = flu.producto) 
  left join especies esp on (esp.especie = pro.especie)
  order by flu.zona, dtr.cod_fundo, flu.producto, flu.destino, sup.codigo");

  $tansporCollect = collect();
  $tansporCollectsinCosto = collect();
  foreach ($var as $f) {
    if($f->codigo != null){    
      if($f->especie == 1){      
        $a = 0.177548*$f->dist_no_pavimento;
        $b = 0.0746*$f->dist_pavimento;
        $c = 0.0333*$f->peaje;
        $costoFundo = ($a + $b + 1.1191 + 0.399 + $c)*$f->sup_ha;
      }
      else{
        $a = 0.1652*$f->dist_no_pavimento;
        $b = 0.0694*$f->dist_pavimento;
        $c = 0.0357*$f->peaje;
        $costoFundo = ($a + $b + 1.0421 + 0.599 + $c)*$f->sup_ha;
      }      
        $tansporC = collect([
          'zona' => $f->zona,
          'destino' => $f->destino,
          'producto' => $f->producto,
          'especie' => $f->especie,
          'costo' => $costoFundo
        ]);
        $tansporCollect->push($tansporC);

        $tansporsinCosto = collect([
          'zona' => $f->zona,
          'destino' => $f->destino,
          'producto' => $f->producto,
          'especie' => $f->especie,
        ]);
        $tansporCollectsinCosto->push($tansporsinCosto);
    }
  }

  $zonas = $tansporCollect->pluck('zona')->toArray();
  $destinos = $tansporCollect->pluck('destino')->toArray();
  $especies = $tansporCollect->pluck('especie')->toArray();

  $zonas =array_values(array_unique($zonas));
  $destinos =array_values(array_unique($destinos));
  $especies =array_values(array_unique($especies));
  
  $transporCollectUnique = $tansporCollectsinCosto->unique();
  for($i = 0; $i<count($zonas); $i++){
        $costoZona = $tansporCollect->where('zona',$zonas[$i]);
        for($z=0; $z<count($destinos); $z++){
          $costoDestino = $costoZona->where('destino',$destinos[$z]);
          for($j=0; $j<count($especies); $j++){
            $costoEspecie = $costoDestino->where('especie',$especies[$j])->avg('costo');
            /*ACA LLAMO A LA SGTE FUNCION*/
            $this->reemplazaCostoZona($zonas[$i],$destinos[$z], $especies[$j], $costoEspecie, $transporCollectUnique); 
          }
        }
      }
```

función reemplazaCostoZona()

```
public function reemplazaCostoZona($zona, $destino, $especie, $costo, $transporCollect){

 $productos = $transporCollect->where([['zona',$zona],['destino', $destino],['especie',$especie]])
                                     ->pluck('producto');
 dd($productos );

}
```

necesito obtener el listado de productos para zona destino y especie,
Es decir que para mi ejemplo de collecion, para zona 1 destino 5 especie 1 tendria en mi listado producto 1 y puede haber mas.

Estoy con `laravel 5.8`

Answer (score 0):

En este segmento de código estas agregando un array de array y altera el funcionamiento de las collections

```
$tansporC = collect([
          'zona' => $f->zona,
          ...
          'costo' => $costoFundo
 ]);
$tansporCollect->push($tansporC);
```

Debes sustituirlo por agregar solo un item

```
$tansporC = [
          'zona' => $f->zona,
          ...
          'costo' => $costoFundo
];
$tansporCollect->push($tansporC);
```

Ademas de que puedes usar la función `unique` de las collections para obtener un solo valor de los posibles repetidos

```
$zonas = $tansporCollect->pluck('zona')->unique()
```

Comment: Seguí tus sugerencias se agradece, pero aún así me sale el mismo error
mi for quedo como foreach segun la recomendación con el unique ya que los indices  no se restablecen de 0 a n http://prntscr.com/tawuk1
Me aseguré tambien de imprimir las variables en la funcion reemplazaCostoZona() y si se "envían" bien